# Issue with changing order of integration in $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y^2}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{ye^x}{x}dxdy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

This is problem no. 5.15. from Vector Analysis and Cartesian Vectors by Kendall.

So, I start with $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y^2}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{ye^x}{x}dxdy$, by drawing the integration area (I've no idea if there is a more rigorous way to do this), I conclude that the appropriate substitution for the boundaries is $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x^2}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{ye^x}{x}dydx$$ 
Then I solve the inner integral and arrive at: $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}e^xdx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}e^xx^4dx$$
The first integral is trivial, and the second I solve by four time partially integrating (I am certain this step is correct):
$$\frac{e-1}{2}-e^x(x^4-4x^3+12x^2-24x+24)|_0^1$$
Which gives me in the end $-4e+\frac{23}{2}$, however, the correct solution should be $\frac{3e}{2}-\frac{7}{2}$. Given that I don't see room for error in the second or the last step, I guess I made the mistake right at the beginning, but I don't know how to diagnose it.

Comment: Second one should be $x^3$ in the integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed a division by $x$ in $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}e^xdx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}e^xx^4dx$$

The  correct version is $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}e^xdx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}e^xx^3dx$$

Comment: it's always stupid mistakes like that, innit?

Comment: @fazan  I am an expert in making stupid mistakes.